# Regex: Select characters at the end, but not the start

Tags: regex

I currently have the following regex function:`[\/*+-]*[\d]`. That is current selecting the following string:

```
`10`ADJLegYld`10/100`+  ADJBoneYld`*12` + ADJBoneYld`+1`  ADJBoneYld`-12`
```

I want to have it select all numbers that start with a special character and the special character itself. Specifically I don't want the numbers infront and behind the word to be selected. Only if it starts with a special character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
[\/*+-]+\d+
```

Change `*` to `+` so it matches at least 1 special character at the beginning.

Add `+` after `\d` so it matches all the digits of the number.

There's no need to put `\d` inside `[]`.